# My escape event isn't working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program that when I press escape on the window appears a label "You pressed Escape".

```
from tkinter import *

class the_Esc_test(Frame):
   def __init__(self):
      Frame.__init__(self)
      self.start_number=0
      self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
      self.master.title("Esc program")
      self.master.geometry ("600x600")

      self.bind("<Escape>", self.EscPressed)

  def EscPressed(self):
     self.start_number+=1
     if self.start_number==1:
         self.lbl1=Label(self, text="You pressed Escape")
         self.lbl1.grid(row=6, column=6, sticky=W)

     elif self.start_number==2:
         self.lbl1.grid_forget()
         self.start_number=0

start=the_Esc_test()
```

It doesn't work, but Python will not show any error.

Can someone show me why?

Comment: When the user presses _enter_, or _escape_? Your description says one, the code says another.

Comment: Sorry, i accidently wrote enter

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work like so

```
from Tkinter import *

class the_Esc_test(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.start_number=0
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title("Esc program")
        self.master.geometry ("600x600")

        self.master.bind("<Escape>", self.EscPressed)

    def EscPressed(self, event):
        print "called", event.keysym

start=the_Esc_test()
start.mainloop()
```